# Pick up pen when turtle is not at coordinate

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My program draws images that already have coordinates attach to them. I want my turtle to be able to pick up the pen when not at the coordinate. Right now the turtle continues to write before getting to the coordinate.

code:

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())

tony = turtle.Turtle()

for z in data:
    position = tony.pos()
    tony.goto(z)
```

***output***

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azdyH.png):[image]

As you can see the turtle continues to draw even before getting to the coordinate.

Here's something I think may work but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
for z in data:
     position = tony.pos()
     while position in z == False:
         tony.penup()

for z in data:
     position = tony.pos()
     while position in z == True:
        tony.pendown()
        print("True")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a function that detected whether the position of the turtle was in the list of coordinates. This function was then called every millisecond using the `ontimer` function. I also had to slow down my turtle in order for the program to check the position within a millisecond

code:

```
tony = turtle.Turtle()
tony.color("white", "cyan")
tony.speed(5.5)

def on_canvas():
    position = tony.pos()
    if position in data:
        tony.pendown()
        print("This is a coordinate")
    else:
        tony.penup()
        print("This is not a coordinate")


for z in data:
    playground.ontimer(on_canvas, 1)
    tony.goto(z)

turtle.done()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try picking up the pen before you move and putting it down after:

```py
with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())

tony = turtle.Turtle()

for z in data:
    tony.penup()
    tony.goto(z)
    tony.pendown()
```

Comment: maybe try adding a signal to pickup and put down the pen or try calculating the distance and picking up the pen if it is within a threshold